# Is there a way to add class in my html element in Django using forms?

Tags: django, class, django-forms

I want to add a  `class`  attribute in my template but my code doesn't work.

I have already tried the other answers from Stackoverflow but none of these worked for me.

```py
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','password']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget = TextInput(attrs={
            'id': 'id_username',
            'class': 'input',
            'placeholder': 'Enter username'})
```

The output have no changes at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do so following this link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

With the help of widgets, you can do that below is the way for doing it.
Just try this.

`from django.forms.widgets import TextInput`

You don't need to override `__init__` method. Just modify your code like below.

```py
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username','password']
    widgets = {
        'username': TextInput(attrs={
            'id': 'id_username',
            'class': 'input',
            'placeholder': 'Enter username'
        })
    }
```

Comment: It returns me an error TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widgets'

Answer (score 0):

You can add the required class in the form init.

```
    class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ['username','password']

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            for field in self.fields:
                self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```